# mysql - trigger when a row created

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, insert

I want to trigger `create new rows` in  `b` table when a row is inserted to `a` table.

I have a table `staff_leave_application` like this:

```
id |  staff     |   leave type  | start date | end date       |  is half  |
---+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
 1 | John Doe   |  Casual Leave | 17/01/2013 | 20/01/2013     |     0     |
```

if a row is inserted in this table, then it will trigger and insert to another table `leave`

the data to be inserted to `leave` table:

Split date range `start date` - `end date` to day, like :

```
17/01/2013 - 20/01/2013 will be

17/01/2013
18/01/2013
19/01/2013
20/01/2013
```

now insert per day to per row of `leave` table, along with `staff_leave_application`s column  `ID, staff, leave type`.

I followed @Shaharsh shah's answer and got this, thanks to Sharsh.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `tn_air_staff_leave_application` AFTER INSERT ON `staff_leave_application` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET @counter := -1; 
        WHILE (@counter < DATEDIFF(DATE(new.end_date), DATE(new.start_date))) DO 
            INSERT INTO `leave`(staff_id_staff, leave_type_id_leave_type, staff_leave_application_id_staff_leave_application, leave_date) 
            VALUES (new.staff_id_staff, new.leave_type_id_leave_type, new.id_staff_leave_application, DATE_ADD(new.start_date, INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 DAY)); 
        END WHILE; 
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `tn_air_staff_leave_application`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `tn_air_staff_leave_application` AFTER INSERT ON `staff_leave_application` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET @counter := -1; 
        WHILE (@counter < DATEDIFF(DATE(new.endDate), DATE(new.startDate))) DO 
            INSERT INTO `leave`(staffId, leaveType, leaveDate) 
            VALUES (new.id, new.leaveType, DATE_ADD(new.startDate, INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 DAY)); 
        END WHILE; 
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**DELETE Trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `tn_adr_staff_leave_application`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `tn_adr_staff_leave_application` AFTER DELETE ON `staff_leave_application` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
          DELETE FROM `leave` WHERE staffId = old.id;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Dear Saharsh, thanks for your time and answering my question. may god bless you. I will tell tomorrow if code works or not. thanks again. Regards Rahul

Comment: Saharsh I want to trigger delete when `staff_leave_application` row deleted then delete all rows in `leave`which have same leave id as application id like `leave.id_leave = staff_leave_application.id_staff_leave_application`

Comment: @user1983017 Check the delete trigger an my updated answer

Comment: OMG your code is working. thanks you so much.